# How do I return an immutable parameter from a method, unchanged, and without a copy in c++?

Tags: c++, immutability

How do I return a parameter from a method, unchanged, and without a copy in c++?

```
// This is more or less the desired signature from the caller's point of view
SomeImmutableObject ManipulateIfNecessary(SomeImmutableObject const& existingObject)
{
    // Do some work…
    // ...

    if (manipulationIsNeccessary)
    {
        // Return a new object with new data etc (preferably without another copy)...
        return SomeImmutableObject(...);
    }
    else
    {
        // Return the original object intact (but with no further copies!)...
        return existingObject;
    }
}
```

An example is C#'s String.Trim method. C# strings are immutable and if Trim doesn't have to do any work, a reference to the existing string is returned, otherwise a new string object with the trimmed content is returned.

How would I mimic this semantic in C++ given something close to the above method signature?

Comment: "otherwise a new string object..." So why do you want to avoid a copy then?

Comment: pass by reference works in the similar way in c++, whats wrong with using the similar code in c++?

Comment: If you're talking about NRVO, I don't think it's applicable here.

Comment: I think what you're looking for is accomplished by the caller doing: `const SomeImmutableObject& foo = ManipulateIfNecessary(existingObject)` - assigning the return value to a const & won't copy it and will instead extend it's life while giving it a name in your caller.

Comment: @Charlie: when manipulation isn't necessary, that will necessarily bind to a *temporary copy* of the `existingObject`, because the function returns by value.

Comment: Folks - Yes, I cannot return by reference since there's a local variable there in the manipulationIsNeccesary branch.  If it helps, I'm in fact wanting to do this for the std::basic_string<T> class in order to implement an efficient Trim actually.  I'll have to profile/measure the solution from @orlp below but that seems interesting.

Comment: BTW - Even though std::basic_string is not Immutable, I want to preserve that semantic so I'm trying not to modify the string in place either.

Answer (score 2):

Your object must be a reference type for this to work. Let's give a toy example for strings:

```
class RefString {
public:
    RefString() : ref(new std::string()) { }
    RefString(const std::string& str) : ref(new std::string(str)) { }

    RefString trim_trailing_newline() {
        if (ref->back() == '\n') {
            return RefString(ref->substr(0, ref->size()-1));
        }

        return *this;
    }

    size_t size() { return ref->size(); }

private:
    std::shared_ptr<std::string> ref;
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    RefString s("test\n");
    std::cout << s.size() << "\n";
    std::cout << s.trim_trailing_newline().size() << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ah, interesting because I'm in fact wanting to implement Trim with the example I provided :)   I'll have to profile this out to see what wins, if any, are gained by using the shared_ptr route like this with my typical input sizes.

Comment: While this solution turned out to be a clear win for strings that did not require actual work to trim, unfortunately it was too heavy for those that do due to the extra memory allocations for shared_ptr usage.  Great pattern though which I'll be keeping around for the future!

Answer (score 1):

A reasonable option is to implement `SomeImmutableObject` in a way that supports this - internally as a reference-counted smart-pointer to the logical state, while externally it may provide value semantics.  (This can complicate usage from threaded code - you may want to read up on copy-on-write (COW) and why it became unpopular for implementing `std::string`.)

If you're stuck with an existing `SomeImmutableObject` implementation you can't change, and you can't wrap it with a reference-counted smart-pointer of sorts, then choices get limited.

It doesn't provide as clean caller usage, but you could make `manipulationIsNeccessary` a caller-accessible function, then have the caller call the *"new object with new data"* code - in a second function:

```
SomeImmutableObject obj;

const SomeImmutableObject& o =
    manipulationIsNecessary(obj) ? newObjectWithNewData(obj) : obj;
...use o...
```

By having `newObjectWithNewData` be a separate function, you should get return value optimisation kicking in (though it's always best to check with your compiler/settings).

Comment: Perhaps I hid too many details from the topic in hopes of not leading, but instead lead down another path :)   In fact I'm trying to impliment an efficient std::basic_string<T> method for both Trim and Split -- in both of these cases a separate 'check' method won't gain much because that method will be producing the necessary data in order to create the new object later - so they have to be kept close together.

Answer (score 1):

You may always return const SomeImmutableObject&. Note though that assigning result to an object will invoke a copy.

```
SomeImmutableObject x = ManipulateIfNecessary(y); // will invoke a copy-ctor
```

The real trick would be the implementation. When the first "if" clause has an effect you will be presumably returning reference to temporary variable (bad thing to do). The newly created object would have to be dynamically allocated.

All, in all I do not think this is easily possible w/o some smart memory management.

Comment: *"The newly created object would have to be dynamically allocated."* - and there's the rub... you could have a flag inside the object record that it was so allocated, and have a `delete_self()` function that only does so if that flag's set, but it's all damned ugly and fragile in client usage....